# Detect FragmentStatePagerAdapter's fragment child calls onViewCreated method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I've a ViewPager with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter attached. Each children is a Fragment. I need to call a couple of methods whenever I scroll in or off from a page. This is what I did so far:

```
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        int mCurrentPosition = -1;

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int newPosition) {
            super.onPageSelected(newPosition);

            FullScreenAssetFragment newPage = (FullScreenAssetFragment) mAdapter.getItem(newPosition);
            newPage.onFragmentScrolledIn();

            if (mCurrentPosition >= 0) {
                FullScreenAssetFragment oldPage = (FullScreenAssetFragment) mAdapter.getItem(mCurrentPosition);
                oldPage.onFragmentScrolledOff();
            }

            mCurrentPosition = newPosition;
        }
    });
```

Then in each Fragment I have this methods implemented:

```
/**
 * Called when this Fragment is hidden from the ViewPager, because we scrolled off to another
 * page.
 */
public void onFragmentScrolledOff() {
    if (mVideoView != null && mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
        mVideoView.stopPlayback();
    }
    if (mMediaController != null) {
        mMediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

/**
 * Called when this Fragment is shown in the ViewPager
 */
public void onFragmentScrolledIn() {
    if (mVideoView != null && !mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
        mVideoView.start();
    }
    if (mMediaController != null) {
        mMediaController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

As you may guess, here the issue is that in each of my Fragments I have a VieoView in which I display videos, and I want to stop those videos when I scroll off to another page. But that's not the main point, I may want to detect scroll changes for other reasons. So any  specific video-related solution is not useful. What I want is to called those methods onFragmentScrolledOff/onFragmentScrolledIn after the Fragment's onViewCreated method has been executed. It happened that I had a variable that I set through the Fragment's Bundle and when I executed the method onFragmentScrolledIn the variable was null, meaning that the onViewCreated method hadn't being called yet. I want that when the onFragmentScrolledOff/onFragmentScrolledIn methods are called, being 100% sure that the onViewCreated method was already called before.

Any advice about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

override `getItemPosition` method in your FragmentStatePagerAdapter class as return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE . Call `onFragmentScrolledIn()` on Fragment's `onCreateView` and call `onFragmentScrolledOff()` on Fragment's `onDetach()` method.

Comment: That's not going to work. I need to call the onFragmentScrolledOff() when the page was scrolled off, not when the onDetach() method is called. The onDetach() method can be called by many other reasons, for example because I exited the Activity/Fragment. Same with the onFragmentScrolledIn(), the onCreateView method is called when the Fragment is created. If I have a ViewPager, with 8 pages and the offset is 1, is going to call the onFragmentScrolledIn() for the current page, the previous one and the next one.

Comment: did you give it a try ?

Comment: No. If I hook that onFragmentScrolledIn in my onCreateView, the method onFragmentScrolledIn  is going to be called event when I'm not using the ViewPager. I use this fragment in several other place where there's no ViewPager.